# MySQL PHP While loop

Tags: php

I'm in need of some help. I'm working in dreamweaver and I'm trying to insert values from my MySQL database into a table on my HTML page.

Dreamweaver generated these variables for me from the server behaviours

```
mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_mwAcc = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
$mwAcc = mysql_query($query_mwAcc, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_mwAcc = mysql_fetch_assoc($mwAcc);
$totalRows_mwAcc = mysql_num_rows($mwAcc);
```

Now what I need help with is what to put into the while loop for my PHP script, this is what I have so far

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <?php while (): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With an update to use PDO you can change the `while` loop into a `foreach` on the query result.  PDO should be used over `mysql_` interface methods, due to deprecation: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

```
<?php
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=...;dbname=...', $user, $pass);
  $results = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM accounts');
?>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <?php foreach ($results as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! for some reason it skips the first entry. I have 6 entries in the database but it starts at 2 and ends at 6. Any advice?

Comment: Make sure that `mysql_fetch_assoc` is only being called in the `while` loop.  In the previous code snippet it was being called above the table block.

Comment: Do not, I repeat, DO NOT, use the mysql_* interface.  Switch to mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your fetch command within the while loop itself.

```
   $query_mwAcc = "SELECT * FROM accounts";

   $mwAcc = mysql_query($query_mwAcc, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

   while($row_mwAcc = mysql_fetch_assoc($mwAcc)) { 
?>      

<tr>
   <td><?php echo $row_mwAcc['id'] ?></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```